# windows server creation from amazon ec2 snapshot

Tags: amazon-ec2, snapshot

I created a windows 2003 instance on Amazon EC2, I created the snapshot for backup. Now I am creating the volume from that snapshot and try to attach to a new windows 2003 server.

I am able to up the new windows 2003 box but I could not login with any password now. Tried all the passwords but could login. Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you have done? The instance is a ebs backed instance? Is it the root device? How/when did you get the first password? Did you change it? What was the password when you made the snapshot? Did you detach the original volume before attaching the volume created from the snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password from the original VM should be on the new one.  Launching a new VM from a self-created AMI that was not prepped to be duplicated will mean it will retain the existing password.

You will not be able to use the 'Retrieve Windows Password' option unless the VM is prepped first.